# Get link of activity for push notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to open particular activity when the push notification is clicked. I am using onesignal push notification service. Onesignal provides a feature of opening particular url on notification click. Now i want to open a particular activity (Suppose Activity_two) on notification click. How can i do that? Like for PlayStore we use `market:\\`...

Answer (score 0):

```
While send push notification from one signal send link or path of   activity .
1. Define deep links in manifest. 
2. Open Launcher activity on click of Notification.
3. Check path in data accepted by activity using uri.getData()
4. On based on data navigate to your desired activity.
```

Comment: any tutorial for the same?

Comment: I dont have any tutorial but once you know deep linking , then you will get to know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first disable OneSignal's default action of opening your launcher Activity when one of it's notifications are tapped on. Add the following `meta-data` element to your `AndroidManifest.xml` under application.

```
<application ...>
   <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
</application>
```

You will then need to setup a `NotificationOpenedHandler` to handle the open event and call your `startActivity(...)`.

```
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class YourAppClass extends Application {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
        .init();
  }

   private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements NotificationOpenedHandler {
      @Override
      public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult openedResult) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Activity_two.class);
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
   }
}
```

OneSignal's full documentation on this.
[Changing the open action of a notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-customizations)